# Gnuplot interpretes locale decimal separator only in the first data line

Tags: gnuplot

My data file is

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
```

I try to plot it with the following script

```
set terminal pngcairo size 600,300 enhanced font "Calibri,18"
set output 'demo_err.png'

set xr [-1:3]
set yr [-1:+1]

#decimal separator in Russia is comma
set decimalsign locale "Russian_Russia.1251"

plot "demo_err.csv" u ($0):(0):(sprintf("%.1f", $1)) w labels,\
```

[image]

As you see, first label is OK, but in second and third label fraction is shown as 0. What am I doing wrong?

Gnuplot version is 5.2.6

Answer (score 2):

"set decimalsign" controls only the output, not the input.
Input is controlled by "set locale".  I can't test this because I don't have your locale installed, but it should work to do

```
set locale "Russian_Russia.1251"
set decimalsign locale "Russian_Russia.1251"

plot "demo_err.csv" u ($0):(0):(sprintf("%.1f", $1)) w labels
```

[Edit] I have now reproduced the problem using a different locale.  What is happening is that each time sprintf is called it sets the locale on entry and resets it to "C" on exit.   If sprintf appears on a gnuplot command line this is exactly what you want to happen.  But if it is called during evaluation of a 'using' specification this clobbers the state of the next data input read operation.  A work-around for your simple test case is to avoid the use of sprintf in the 'using' spec:

```
plot "demo_err.csv" u ($0):(0):(stringcolumn(1)) w labels
```

I do not know if an equivalent work-around  is possible for your full use case by avoiding sprintf inside the "using" clause of the plot command.  Meanwhile I will file a bug report on the gnuplot issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't help. In the manual it is stated, that _set decimalsign ","_ controls output and influences only _gprintf()_ behaviour (and it is really so). But _set decimalsign locale_ controls both input and output with _sprintf()_. What is strange, first line is interpreted correctly. I tried to change lines order and even add headers. And in all cases first data line is interpreted correctly.

Comment: Yes, this example works. Tried to use _gprintf()_ instead of _sprintf()_, but with the same result. Finally I came to the obvious solution: (1) dots in input, (2) set decimalsign ",", (3) _grprintf()_ for output and concatenation for complex output. Anyway the main thing is output, input is not seen by anybody.

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't wait until the bug is fixed and @Ethan's `stringcolumn(1)` suggestion is not enough, because you "absolutely" need e.g. the format `"%.3f"`, you can mimic `sprintf("%.3f",x)` with a formula. Well, with the drawback... it is not rounding the decimals, but truncating.

**Script:**

```
### sprintf("%.nf",x) "replacement" with decimalsign locale ','
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1
-2,34567
123,45
5,6
7,8867
EOD

set locale "Russian_Russia.1251"
set decimalsign locale "Russian_Russia.1251"
set offset 1,1,1,1

mySprintf(col,n) = (s=strcol(col),c=strstrt(s,','), s.',0000000'[sgn(c)+1:])[1: c ? c+n : strlen(s)+n+1] 

plot $Data u (1):0:(mySprintf(1,3)) w labels
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I came to a solution that is in comment to @Ethan’s post. I am a novice to Gnuplot, but definitely it is great in finding work-arounds. There are already three, and all fit me.